# How to select node containing plain text and some other nodes by its texts?

Tags: xpath

Given the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <a>Something 1</a>
     > 
    <a>Something 2</a>
     > Something 3
</div>
```

I want to select div by text `> Something 3` using XPath.

So I checked xpath `//div[contains(text(), '> Something 3')]` but this does not return any nodes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this:

```
//div[contains(string(), '> Something 3')]
```

**OR**

```
//div[contains(., '> Something 3')]
```